# Shell Script help to copy directory them remove

Tags: linux, shell

I want to write simple script to copy/backup directory then remove on server startup. So something like this:

```
TC_DIR=${SERVER_HOME}/terracotta
CLUSTER_STAT_DIR=${TC_DIR}/cluster-stat

cp ${CLUSTER_STAT_DIR} ${TC_DIR}/old.cluster-stat
rm ${CLUSTER_STAT_DIR}
```

Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you have done should work with the only addition that you need to pass -r options to both cp and rm as you are dealing with directories. Try this:

```
TC_DIR=${SERVER_HOME}/terracotta
CLUSTER_STAT_DIR=${TC_DIR}/cluster-stat

cp -r ${CLUSTER_STAT_DIR} ${TC_DIR}/old.cluster-stat
rm -rf ${CLUSTER_STAT_DIR}
```

EDIT: if your question is how to execute that on startup take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036/linux-files-and-scripts-that-execute-on-boot).

Comment: Forgot was working with directories, thanks for fast response izomorphius

Comment: Actually made improvement to it by using mv instead of cp and rm